# What does this construction mean: bool operator == (const a& other) const;?

Tags: c++, syntax, struct, operators

I have a structure defined in the following way:

```
struct struct_name
{
    int x;
    region y;

    bool operator == (const struct_name& other) const;
};
```

I do not understand the last line in the body of the structure. What does it do?

Comment: I see this question has two down votes but no comment as to why. The question seems very clearly put.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declares `operator==` for this `struct`. This operator will allow you to compare struct objects in an intuitive way:

```
struct_name a;
struct_name b;
if( a == b )
// ...
```

---

```
bool operator == (const struct_name& other) const;
^^^^              ^^^^^............^        ^^^^^-- the method is `const` 1
^^^^              ^^^^^............^
^^^^              ^^^^^............^--- the `other` is passed as const reference
^^^^
^^^^-- normally, return true, if `*this` is the same as `other`
```

`1` - this means, that the method does not change any members

---

**EDIT:** Note, that in `C++`, the only difference between `class` and `struct` is the default access and default type of inheritance (noted by @AlokSave) - `public` for `struct` and `private` for `class`.

Comment: note that it only defines that such an operator is exists (the linker will search for it). There is no implementation for this function defined in this piece of code (it is probably defined somewhere else).

Comment: @PhilippAumayr - that's why I wrote `declares`, not `defines`.

Comment: +1: nitpick: *"the only difference between class and struct....."* and that inheritance by default is `private` for class while `public` for structure.

Answer (score 3):

It declares a function. The function's name is `operator==`. It returns `bool` and takes a single argument of type `const struct_name&`. It final `const` in the line says that it is a const member function, which means that it doesn't modify the state of the `struct_name` object it is called on.

This is known as [operator overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/150634).